# Solr geofilt returning all results

Tags: solr

I am running Solr 5.4 (on Ubuntu server) and indexing from MySQL.  It is working great for searching and faceting, but now I want to implement geospatial filtering.  In the admin UI I run,

```
http://mysite:8983/solr/core/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&spatial=true&pt=44.8859987%2C-93.0833396&sfield=org_loc&d=50
```

Schema:

```
 <field name="org_loc" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

Response:

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":13,
    "params":{
        "lowercaseOperators":"true",
        "d":"50",
        "spatial":"true",
        "indent":"true",
        "q":"*:*",
        "sfield":"org_loc",
        "pt":"44.8859987,-93.0833396",
        "stopwords":"true",
        "wt":"json",
        "defType":"edismax"}},
    "response":{"numFound":21,"start":0,"docs":[
      "org_name": "..."
      "org_loc":"44.8259987,-93.0813396",
      ...etc.
```

The problem is that it returns 21 of 21 records every time, regardless of d.

Comment: may be you have only 21 records with that matching criteria ? did you check with other input ?

Comment: The db has 21 total records with bogus data for test.  It returns all 21 records regardless of pt or d.

Comment: d  is the radial distance, usually in kilometers , please increase this value to 100 and test once

Comment: then there is no issue right ?

Comment: I said regardless of d.  I've tried 5, 50, 500, 5000.  It returns 21 records every time, whether the returned records fall inside or outside of the radius.

Comment: I believe all your lat long are pretty close , please paste all 21 lat long once , that might be the reason it is giving all

Comment: They're not all close.  I have 20 points scattered around the US and one in Europe.

Comment: try rows=5 and check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geofilt` must be required explicitly using the `fq` parameter, this part of the query is missing :

```
&fq={!geofilt}
```

Comment: That works! I tried geofilt many times before, even pasting this line straight out of the manual: &q=*:*&fq={!geofilt sfield=org_loc}&pt=44.8859987,-93.0833396&d=50, but it doesn't work.  Oddly, it does work when I enter {!geofilt} in the fq parameter of the admin UI, which generates this: &fq={!geofilt}&spatial=true&pt=44.8659987%2C-93.0823396&sfield=org_loc&d=500 (plus other relevant params).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!